# Альтернативы phonegap?

Tags: phonegap, adobe-air, mobile-development

p.s. Кроме adobe air.

p.p.s. Уж больно глюкнутая эта штука - phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/95010/ - titanium mobile (javascript)

http://docs.rhomobile.com/ - rhomobile (javascript)

unity3d (C#)

qt creator for ios, android (C++)

http://xamarin.com/ - monodroid (C#)